# Get objects' index in a Java List

Tags: java, android, list, indexing

I have a list of strings in my (Android) Java program, and I need to get the index of an object in the list. The problem is, I can only find documentation on how to find the first and last index of an object. What if I have 3 or more of the same object in my list? How can I find *every* index?

Thanks!

Comment: what about: yourList.indefOf(yourObjectInList); I am using java.util.ArrayList and method indexOf(..) works just fine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to do a brute force search:

```
  static <T> List<Integer> indexesOf(List<T> source, T target)
  {
     final List<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
     for (int i = 0; i < source.size(); i++) {
       if (source.get(i).equals(target)) { indexes.add(i); }
     }
     return indexes;
  }
```

Note that this is not necessarily the most efficient approach.  Depending on the context and the types/sizes of lists, you might need to do some serious optimizations.  The point is, if you need every index (and know nothing about the structure of the list contents), then you need to do a deathmarch through every item for at best O(n) cost.

Depending on the type of the underlying list, `get(i)` may be O(1) (`ArrayList`) or O(n) (`LinkedList`), so this COULD blow up to a O(n<sup>2</sup>) implementation.  You could copy to an `ArrayList`, or you could walk the `LinkedList` incrementing an index counter manually.

Comment: How can I optimize? My list is around 8,000 items. This code would run in a thread, but still, I don't want to show a "Please wait..." dialog forever.

Comment: 1) Don't optimize until you have a performance goal and can measure; 2) If you have an `ArrayList`, the above should work fine; 3) If not, suggest you either switch to using an `ArrayList` OR adjust as I suggest above...

Comment: if index of every matched element is required then every element of the list has to be checked. what could be a another way

Comment: Alternatively, maybe you need to maintain this list as a sorted/ordered list, in which case a more efficient solution is quite a bit easier.  Say more about your application -- what is this a list OF?

Comment: Cool, thank's guys. I'll give this a go and see how it works out!

Comment: @Javanator:  1) You're right, but for some `List` implementations, `get(int index)` requires at worst an entire list traversal, so that can be avoided; 2) If you know something about the structure of your data, maybe you can maintain the list in an order such that a comprehensive brute-force search is not required.

Comment: @Javanator:  For an interesting exercise, just try implementing the algorithm and measure the difference between applying it to the same data stored in an `ArrayList` and `LinkedList`.... as the # of entries increases, you may be surprised by the different execution time growth rates.

Answer (score 2):

If documentation is not helping me in my logic in this situation i would have gone for a raw approach for Traversing the list in a loop and saving the index where i found a match

```
 ArrayList<String> obj = new ArrayList<String>();


 obj.add("Test Data"):  // fill the list with your data

 String dataToFind = "Hello";

 ArrayList<Integer> intArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();

 for(int i = 0 ; i<obj.size() ; i++)
 {
    if(obj.get(i).equals(dataToFind)) intArray.add(i);     
 } 

 now intArray would have contained all the index of matched element in the list
```

Comment: If the size of list is big then this will need optimization to apply . else for small size list this wont create a problem

Answer (score 1):

An alternative brute force approach that will also find all `null` indexes:

```
static List<Integer> indexesOf(List<?> list, Object target) {
    final List<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int offset = 0;
    for (int i = list.indexOf(target); i != -1; i = list.indexOf(target)) {
        indexes.add(i + offset);
        list = list.subList(i + 1, list.size());
        offset += i + 1;
    }
    return indexes;
}
```